# execute Paypal payouts API with curl -> response 401

Tags: curl, paypal

```
curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
-d '{
    \"sender_batch_header\":{
    \"email_subject\":\"You have a Payout!\",
  },
  \"items\":[
    {
      \"recipient_type\":\"EMAIL\",
      \"amount\":{
        \"value\":\"11.0\",
        \"currency\":\"USD\"
      },
      \"note\":\"Thanks for your patronage!\",
      \"sender_item_id\":\"2014031400011\",
      \"receiver”:”<email>\"
    }
  ]'
```

excute, and response 401. 
auth token value is correct. 
why response 401? it means unauthorized. but header is CORRECT. help plz

Comment: syntax is good check your token once ?

Comment: IPN check is working. only not work payout email.